# Why apcupsd won't see the UPS connected to the USB posrt on FreeBSD 8.0 amd64

Tags: freebsd, 64-bit

Recently I installed an apcusbd on a FreeBSD 8.0 amd64 box via ports system. It installed perfectly but it won't run.

Here what is says in the log: `FATAL ERROR in generic-usb.c at line 636 Cannot find UPS 
device`

It appeared that HID driver picked the `/dev/ugen4.2` which could cause the apcusb being 
unable to find the device.  After I had discovered this, I rebuilt the kernel and removed the hid driver. Now it just shows "`ugen4.2: <Tripp Lite> at usbus4`" and no `uhid0` device appears.

Nevertheless the problem persisted. I tried to leave the `DEVICE` config setting blank ---  won't help. Then I specified the particular device in the config, but it did not help either.

Below you is the output of several commands that can provide some useful information on my case.

```
server# /usr/local/etc/rc.d/apcupsd start
Starting apcupsd.

server# tail /var/log/messages | grep apcupsd
Jun 17 22:30:00 server apcupsd[1520]: apcupsd FATAL ERROR in generic-usb.c at line 636 
Cannot find UPS device -- For a link to detailed USB trouble shooting information, please 
see .
Jun 17 22:30:00 server apcupsd[1520]: apcupsd error shutdown completed

server# cat /usr/local/etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf
## apcupsd.conf v1.1 ##
UPSCABLE usb
UPSTYPE usb
DEVICE /dev/ugen4.2
LOCKFILE /var/lock
UPSCLASS standalone
UPSMODE disable

server# dmesg | grep '^u'
uhci0:  port 0xa800-0xa81f irq 16 at device 26.0 on pci0
uhci0: [ITHREAD]
uhci0: LegSup = 0x0f00
usbus0:  on uhci0
uhci1:  port 0xa880-0xa89f irq 21 at device 26.1 on pci0
uhci1: [ITHREAD]
uhci1: LegSup = 0x0f00
usbus1:  on uhci1
uhci2:  port 0xac00-0xac1f irq 18 at device 26.2 on pci0
uhci2: [ITHREAD]
uhci2: LegSup = 0x0f00
usbus2:  on uhci2
usbus3: EHCI version 1.0
usbus3:  on ehci0
uhci3:  port 0xa080-0xa09f irq 23 at device 29.0 on pci0
uhci3: [ITHREAD]
uhci3: LegSup = 0x0f00
usbus4:  on uhci3
uhci4:  port 0xa400-0xa41f irq 19 at device 29.1 on pci0
uhci4: [ITHREAD]
uhci4: LegSup = 0x0f00
usbus5:  on uhci4
uhci5:  port 0xa480-0xa49f irq 18 at device 29.2 on pci0
uhci5: [ITHREAD]
uhci5: LegSup = 0x0f00
usbus6:  on uhci5
usbus7: EHCI version 1.0
usbus7:  on ehci1
uart0:  port 0x3f8-0x3ff irq 4 flags 0x10 on acpi0
uart0: [FILTER]
usbus0: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus1: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus2: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus3: 480Mbps High Speed USB v2.0
usbus4: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus5: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus6: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus7: 480Mbps High Speed USB v2.0
ugen0.1:  at usbus0
uhub0:  on usbus0
ugen1.1:  at usbus1
uhub1:  on usbus1
ugen2.1:  at usbus2
uhub2:  on usbus2
ugen3.1:  at usbus3
uhub3:  on usbus3
ugen4.1:  at usbus4
uhub4:  on usbus4
ugen5.1:  at usbus5
uhub5:  on usbus5
ugen6.1:  at usbus6
uhub6:  on usbus6
ugen7.1:  at usbus7
uhub7:  on usbus7
uhub0: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub1: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub2: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub4: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub5: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub6: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub3: 6 ports with 6 removable, self powered
uhub7: 6 ports with 6 removable, self powered
ugen4.2:  at usbus4
server#
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have better luck [asking the APCUPSd guys](http://www.apcupsd.com/lists.html). I've never configured it for anything but a serial APC UPS.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar config on linux which also didn't work.

For me editing apcupsd.conf by changing the line

DEVICE /dev/ugen4.2

to simply

DEVICE

got it working. Seems if you're connecting over USB it can work it out and doesn't need to be told which device to use.

Comment: This should work. It's what the commented configuration file recommends on many platforms.